# how to disable my button in this script?

Tags: jquery

this is my script,here i'l changing the images on button click,which is in array.how should i make disable the button after the condition get false.

```js
var images=["image1","image2","image3"];
var count=0;

$("button").on('click', function(){
 if (count>=images.length) return;
 $(".img_src").attr('src','images/' + images[count] + '.jpg');
   count++;
 console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<div class="image_area">
<img class="img_src my_image" src="images/image1.jpg"/>
</div> 
<button >clickme</button>
```

Comment: add attribute disable to button

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly give your button an id and bind you event using that because binding to button means any button you add to your form will use that action. You've not specified what 'the condition is false' means so I assume this is if your count gets to the last image.

```js
var images=["image1","image2","image3"];
var count=0;

$("#btnNext").on('click', function(){
 if (count>=images.length) 
 {
  $("#btnNext").attr('disabled', true);
  return;
 }
 $(".img_src").attr('src','images/' + images[count] + '.jpg');
   count++;
 console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<div class="image_area">
<img class="img_src my_image" src="images/image1.jpg"/>
</div> 
<button id="btnNext">clickme</button>
```

If you want to re-enable your button later use:

```
$("btnNext").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method and add this to your condition `$("button").attr('disabled', true);` and if you want to enable the button just make `true`, `false`